# What are some ways to get around an in-person final round interview (due to being out-of-state)?

Tags: travel, expenses

So I'm actively looking for a new position, but unfortunately most of them are calling for a move out of state. At one company they invited me for an in-person, and I asked them if they'd be willing to sponsor it, which I was told it was something they'd consider etc. etc.

Is there a good way to work around that requirement, or am I out of touch with today's market for requesting travel expenses? 
Additionally, should the recruiter be willing to sponsor the cost perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You could suggest doing a Skype interview though for a final round interview though this presumes the distance is rather non-trivial, e.g. moving from California to Texas, as there are some out of state moves that I wouldn't see as being that onerous, e.g. if I lived near Detroit and had to go to a Toledo suburb.

The big issue here is how desperate is the company. As an example, if Amazon.com comes to Calgary, Alberta to recruit for US positions, then they are paying the cost but are having a hard time finding quality candidates. In contrast, Microsoft may not come up to Calgary for an interview and would rather prefer local candidates.